# number of affixies in a group

Tags: texstudio

I'm trying to add some affixies in aff file.
I noticed , that only 3 affixes in the group do work all others are ignored.
Here is a demo setup

'ka_GE.aff' file:

```
SET UTF-8
TRY აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ'
MAXNGRAMSUGS 0

CIRCUMFIX X
PFX A Y 9
PFX A 0 აა/X .
PFX A 0 გაა/X .
PFX A 0 მია/X .
PFX A 0 დაა/X .
PFX A 0 აი/X .
PFX A 0 გაი/X .
PFX A 0 ამოა/X .
PFX A 0 ზე/X .
PFX A 0 დამა/X .

SFX C Y 5
SFX C ი ა/AX ი 
SFX C ი ე/AX ი 
SFX C ი ებ/AX ი 
SFX C ი და/AX ი 
SFX C ი დება/AX ი 


REP 4
ტ  თ
რ  ღ
თ  ტ
ღ  რ
```

and 'ka_Ge.dic' file:

```
1
ბრიალი/C
```

and document (TeXStudio) looks like this:

[image]

If i remove 'REP' staff everything works fine, but with 'REP' staff and/or with other affixes only the first 3 affixes participate in prosess with CIRCUMFIX X.
I trued to split long affixes group 3 by 3 but no succes.

Is this Tesstudio bug or i'm missing something?

here is a MWE for easy testing:

```
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage[english,georgian]{babel}
        \setmainfont{Dejavu Serif}
        \begin{document}
        ააბრიალა
        ააბრიალებ
        ააბრიალე
        ააბრიალდა

        გააბრიალა
        გააბრიალებ
        გააბრიალე
        გააბრიალდა

        მიაბრიალა
        მიაბრიალე
        მიაბრიალებ
        მიაბრიალდა

        დააბრიალა
        დააბრიალე
        დააბრიალებ
        დააბრიალდა

        \end{document}
```

p.s.
maybe this is out of scope of this community, but can you suggest appropriate one?

Comment: I found that this REP staff causes problem..if i move it in the begining after 'set utf-8' affixis does not work at all...At the end it behaves as i have mentioned above in the post